# What is the second JobConf argument in Hadoop's ChainMapper.addMapper method for?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

What is the second JobConf argument in Hadoop's ChainMapper.addMapper, ChainReducer.setReducer, and ChainReducer.addMapper methods for?

I assumed that it would be a place for settings that are relevant only to the Mapper or Reducer I'm adding, but parameters I set on the second JobConf are not present when the Mapper or Reducer is called.

```
JobConf overall = new JobConf( Driver.class );
JobConf mapAConf = new JobConf( false );
mapAConf.setInt( "min.word.length", 10 );
ChainMapper.addMapper( overall, Mapper.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, false, mapAConf );
ChainReducer.setReducer( overall, Reducer.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, false, new JobConf( false ) );
```

In this example the min.word.length value is not set in the mapper class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post a short segment of code where you show how you are calling the "min.word.length" in the mapper. That might help diagnose the problem

Comment: Also to answer the question in the title, the last argument IS for mapper settings.